# R Package Vignette Include API Key

Tags: r, environment-variables, r-package, vignette

I'm creating a vignette in RMarkdown for a package that requires a secret API key. I'm including the key as an environment variable, and then using this key as an argument; but when I check the package build, I get a Warning because it can't read my environment variable.

If I pass in the key directly into the function, I don't get the Warning.

Here is the Warning:

```
Error: processing vignette '' failed with diagnostics:
second argument must be a list
Execution halted
```

My code looks

```
 apikey = Sys.getenv('key')

 house_enacted_115 <- getBills(apikey,"115","house","enacted",1,20)
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I just added the code to the question

Comment: How are you creating the environment variable?

Comment: Don't do this. You'd have to give out the key insecurely at some point. Cache the data, `eval=FALSE` the code chunks that grab data from the API in the vignette, `echo=FALSE` the ones that actually read the cached data. You don't need the vignettes to exercise the API, just explain the API to the users. Similarly, have your tests `skip_on_cran()` and `\dontrun{}` your examples. Then securely use your API keys on Travis and note the Travis link in your CRAN submission so they can validate regular testing occurs.

Comment: (I may have made an API pkg or three ;-)

Comment: I have a similar issue I am writing a vignette for an r package but the function needs an api key?